# Redirect die messages to a file

Tags: perl

I'm opening a file like below:

```
open (my $fh, '<', $query_file) or die "Query for specified metric does not exist : $!";
my $query = <$fh>;
close $fh;
```

When the file does not exist it writes the error message on console but I would like to save this message in a file.

How it can be done?

Comment: Why it is marked as duplicate? did i post it twice?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the specified answered question. The OP is wanting to know how to redirect messages from `die()` to a file, not how to write to a file...

Comment: The simplest way is to redirect the program's STDERR, which would also catch warnings. e.g. `script.pl 2>log` Other options include running your entire program in an `eval { }` or you could hook into `$SIG{__DIE__}`. Neither of these will catch warnings, which matches your request, but are unlikely what you actually want.

Answer (score 4):

From [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24SIG%7Bexpr%7D)

> The routine indicated by `$SIG{__DIE__}` is called when a fatal
>   exception is about to be thrown. The error message is passed as the
>   first argument.

You can use it like below:

```
local $SIG{__DIE__} = sub {
    my ($die_message) = @_;
    open (my $log, ">>", '/tmp/die.log');
    print $log $die_message;
};
```